# SQL Server 2008 R2 size limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I just want to know if what will happen if I already consumed the space available for my database? Is there any way on how to increase its maximum size because as far [Screenshot of my space available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcNKH.png) as I know SQL Server 2008 R2 Express has ONLY 4GB max size.

Comment: The size limit *per database* has been increased to **10 GB** as of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Comment: how to increase the size to 10 GB?

Comment: You don't need to increase anything - the limit is just set to 10 GB for 2008 R2 and newer

Comment: Sir, if it is 10 GB already why my space available is just a little. As you can see on the attached image my space available is only 614 MB left and I have consumed 1.3 GB already?